# Check if a PDF file is corrupted with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, windows

Ideally I want to avoid using gems, as I am currently using: `pdf-reader`, `combine-pdf` and `origami`

Each gem if it comes across a damaged pdf sometimes doesn't send an exception but stays there and does nothing.

So I would like you to please help me with a code to see if the file is damaged or not.

I have noticed that some pdf files do not have hexadecimal `(hex 25 50 44 46 | %PDF)` but I'm afraid it's not a universal solution.

Besides all those gems sometimes throw exceptions even when the pdf does work, but at least if I'm sure the pdf works, I'll know what to do.

I could start there. How do I read hexadecimal with ruby? Is the only way to check a pdf?

Comment: You're on a linux platform?

Comment: If you have a file that doesn't contain the `%PDF` header magic, you don't have a PDF file. Anyway, what you are asking for is essentially to provide you with a full PDF parser implementation. On top of that, you aren't even content with an ISO-compliant parser, you want it to exclude certain valid documents that your 'gems' cannot deal with, as well as allow some invalid documents that those libraries can digest. This is **way** to broad a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = IO.binread('file.pdf', 4).unpack("H*").first
valid_pdf = result == '25504446'
```

Will do the comparison for those first 4 bytes

Comment: Thanks helped me, is the only way to check if a pdf is damaged?

Comment: That code checks for presence of the PDF header magic (and fails to even do that reliably). It doesn't attempt to verify data integrity. That's not useful. @tal: If you need to test data integrity you'll inevitably have to write a full PDF parser.

Comment: agreed - too bad pdf doesn't come with a checksum, It sounded like some of his PDF generation was total failure i.e. not even a header was being written. The real solution is to use an exteral library which is not part of this solution.

Comment: @IInspectable The gems I'm using are malysms in my case, they're slow and I've only used them because I can't find documentation to manipulate pdf with pure ruby (which is what I'd like). I don't mind programming a PDF parser from scratch but what are the rules to follow? is what I don't know. Come on, the external bookstore is made of ruby, so why can't you do without gems?

Comment: @tal: Ruby can read files, that's all you need. And 198 CHF to purchase the [ISO 32000-1:2008](https://www.iso.org/standard/51502.html) standard. Depending on your familiarity with PDF, plan anywhere from half a year to several years until you have written a parser from scratch.

Comment: @IInspectable Interesting, I didn't know, but yes, that's what I was looking for. ISO 32000-1:2008 does not specify the following: methods for validating the conformance of PDF files or readers. Won't be a problem? apart, so someone who made a gem to analyze PDF should have studied that ISO?

Comment: @tal: ISO 32000-1:2008 lists requirements a conforming reader must meet. I'm not aware of any methods or tools to verify the conformance of any given reader implementation. Anyone who has published a gem is just that: any random contributor on the internet. There is no requirement for a gem author to have read the ISO standard. Adobe has released 6 editions of the PDF specification prior to standardization. The [sixth edition](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) is freely available for download. That's what authors usually take to (if at all).

Answer (score 2):

I've hit this situation before when verifying grub bootloaders with ruby. I found the easiest solution was to do a pre-check of the hex that I know is supposed to exist. Something along the lines of this:

```
result = `hexdump pdf_file.pdf | head -n 1`
valid_pdf = result.split(" ")[1..2] == ["2550", "4446"]
```

Over time you can expand your check to look for other bad pdfs ahead of time.

One good practice to circumvent the locks on your pdf hangs, is to use the [`Timeout` functionality in ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) This way you can properly exit and not have to forcefully shutdown your program.

Comment: Hi. I'm working on windows, your code doesn't work for me :( `timeout` I knew him but he wasn't useful to me in my case (long history).

Comment: @talC best I can do is point you to https://superuser.com/a/1247756/1168

Comment: This checks whether a file claims to be a PDF file. It does *nothing* to verify document integrity (other than pointing out, that that needs to be done, *somehow*). This is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
File.read(pdf_filepath, 4) == "%PDF"
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?